# Database multiple choice Questi0n table relationship

Tags: database, database-design, relationship

I have a question-answer system. A question has 4 choices and 1 answer(there is no correct answer, it is just user's answer). So how should I make the relationship between these 3 tables? Is it correct what I did below? It is like something is missing in Question table as I have 4 choices(how will I insert them?)

```
Question Table: QuestionId, QuestionText
Choice Table: ChoiceId, ChoiceText, QuestionId
Answer Table: AnswerId, ChoiceId, QuestionId, UserId
```

Thank you in advance. This is my first question in stackoverflow :)

Have a nice day,

Alper

Answer (score 0):

Since `ChoiceId` already identified a `QuestionId`, then you could get rid of `QuestionId` in  `Answer` table if you want full normalization in your data.

I would use the following structure though:

```
create table questions (
    question_id number primary key,
    question_text text
);
create table questions_choices (
    question_id number references questions(question_id),
    choice_number number,
    choice_text text,
    primary key(question_id, choice_number)
);
create table answers (
    answer_id number primary key,
    user_id number references users(user_id),
    question_id number,
    choice_number number,
    foreign key (question_id, choice_number) references questions_choices(question_id, choice_number)
);
```

Which is similar to what you have but without a surrogate key on `questions_choices` table.